# How to copy assets database to inside database?

Tags: android, database, kotlin, copy, assets

```
package org.techtown.testrecyclerview

import android.content.Context
import java.io.*

private val DB_PATH = "/data/data/org.techtown.testrecyclerview/databases/"
private val DB_NAME = "food_nutri.db"

private fun copyDataBaseFromAssets(context: Context) {

    var myInput: InputStream? = null
    var myOutput: OutputStream? = null
    try {

        val folder = context.getDatabasePath("databases")


        if (!folder.exists())
            if (folder.mkdirs()) folder.delete()

        myInput = context.assets.open("databases/$DB_NAME")

        val outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME

        val f = File(outFileName)


        if (f.exists())
            return

        myOutput = FileOutputStream(outFileName)

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var length: Int = myInput.read(buffer)

        while (length > 0) {
            myOutput!!.write(buffer, 0, length)
            length = myInput.read(buffer)
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput!!.flush()
        myOutput.close()
        myInput.close()


    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

}
```

I used this code to copy database in the assets folder to application database.
But It is not working....

Before using this code, I have another db in this path "/data/data/org.techtown.testrecyclerview/databases/".
This is the matter????

```
class AssetDatabaseOpenHelper(private val context: Context) {

companion object {

    private val DB_NAME = "food_nutri.db"
}

fun openDatabase(): SQLiteDatabase {
    val dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME)


    if (!dbFile.exists()) {
        try {
           val checkDB = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null)

            checkDB?.close()
            copyDatabase(dbFile)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e)
        }

    }
    return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
}

@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
private fun copyDatabase(dbFile: File) {
    val `is` = context.assets.open(DB_NAME)
    val os = FileOutputStream(dbFile)

    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
    while (`is`.read(buffer) > 0) {
        os.write(buffer)
        Log.d("#DB", "writing>>")
    }

    os.flush()
    os.close()
    `is`.close()
    Log.d("#DB", "completed..")
}
}
```

And I also used this one, too.
But it also did not work.

I just want to copy the database in assets folder to here "/data/data/org.techtown.testrecyclerview/databases/" , my inside database.
Please help me....
What is the problem?..   :( :(
(Please let me know using Kotlin...)

Comment: `if (folder.mkdirs()) folder.delete()` ???????

Comment: `. This is the matter????` No.

Comment: `if (!dbFile.exists())` Remove that. Just overwrite the old one.

Comment: `val outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME` You are not using `folder`

Comment: `if (f.exists())
            return` Remove that if you want to overwrite the old file.

Comment: Thank you, all of guys!!
And I have one more question.
"private fun copyDataBaseFromAssets(context: Context)" here, to make work this function what should I put of the context??
copyDataBaseFromAssets(#here!!)